Parody of early D&D rules set, and specifically character creation, as part of a web novel of some kind
I'm looking (with no luck so far) for a story I read online at least a decade ago. It had some specific interpretations of early D&D rules that are, at best, controversial but I'd like to reference for playing a rather silly short adventure with some friends, as they added up to make a fun-but-broken set of characters.
I remember the following about it:

The protagonist was a non-minmaxed Paladin, which was quite unusual in the story
The characters mention their stat blocks and builds at various points, but are very much characters rather than just mouthpieces for (not-shown) players
It was a TSR-edition D&D rules set that was used, most likely first edition
Most of the rest of the characters that were relevant to the story were various minmaxed powergamers
The story was translated into several languages, and I'm not sure if it was originally in English
At some point someone kills Atlas, who was holding up the world
It was from the 90s or early 2000s

If anyone has a link to it, or knows the name of the story, or could point me towards any resources about how the setting applied the rules, I'd really appreciate it.

Are you looking for the Intercontinental Union of Disgusting Characters?

AD&D rules.
Ringman the Bearded is a non-optimized paladin.
Most characters are maximized, with 18 in all stats and perfect rolls on various encounter and treasure tables.

There is a larger series, including a sequel about the children and a second sequel series, available on the author's website.

Yeah, definitely it - just read it, and every listed detail matches (Atlas dies in the sequel).

Yes, this is it, thanks so much!
